# Meaning of R's coxph output

Tags: r, cox-model

I am getting below output from `coxph` function in R.

```
Concordance= 0.581  (se = 0.024 )
Rsquare= 0.06   (max possible= 0.995 )
Likelihood ratio test= 11.52  on 3 df,   p=0.009216
```

Can somebody explain what do `11.52` and `0.009216` mean in this output? I assume `11.52` is the prediction of overall survival and `0.009216` is the significance of that prediction, but I am not quite sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

11.52 is the $X^2$ statistic from a likelihood ratio test, and $p$ is the p-value from a $\chi^2$ test with 3 degrees of freedom for that statistic. It's comparing whether your model fits the data "significantly" better than the null model (no predictors at all). It's not the baseline survival.

Comment: Interestingly, with the same data both in Stata and R, we get the same coef, hazard ratio, but different Chi2 statistics value (here: 11.52) even if we set the method "breslow" in R's `coxph`.